# Using open subsets, why is 1/x not a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Looking at this theorem of continuous function by Bert Mendelson in "Introduction to Topology" ch 3, theorem 5.3:

A function $f: (X, T) \rightarrow (Y, T')$ is continuous if and only if for each open subset $O$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is an open subset of $X$.

This follows from the definition of continuous functions which is continuous at each point, after he defined continuous at a point.

However, if I just focus on the theorem:

Now let's take as an example the function $f(x) = 1/x$, and an open subset of $Y$ which I choose to be $(-1, 1)$, the preimage of this subset is $(-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$. Now, as far as I'm concerned this is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then for it not to be continuous I should be able to find an open subset of $Y$ such that the preimage is not an open subset of $X$. However, I cannot find such a subset.

I would like to understand why $1/x$ is not a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ using open subsets (not an epsilon and delta answer)

Comment: 1/x is not a function on R at all. It's a function on R\{0}.

Comment: So it is in fact continuous because it's continuous at every point in it's domain?

Comment: To complement what happens on the non-zero reals, it probably helps to consider what happens if we pick a real number $L$ arbitrarily and define $f(0) = L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ **is continuous**.
Here, we are seeing $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ as a topological space with the *subspace topology*: A subset of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is open if it is the intersection of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ with an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand, the function $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
1/x & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x=0
\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous: $(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, but $g^{-1}((-1,1)) = (-\infty,-1) \cup \{0\} \cup (1,\infty)$ is not.

Comment: Thank you for the example, what about h(x) = 2, for x < 0 and h = 3 for x >= 0. Clearly, this should not be continuous. Then, h^-1((1,5)) = R. I don't see where we can fail to get an open subset

Comment: @CedricMartens You're welcome! Observe that $h^{-1}((2.5,3.5)) = [0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, the function $f(x)=1/x$ is not a function on $\Bbb{R}$; it's a function on $\Bbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$, and in fact it is continuous on this domain.

When people say "$1/x$ is discontinuous", what they mean is that there is no continuous extension of this function to $\Bbb{R}$. For instance, let $g : \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be defined by $g(0)=0$ and $g(x)=1/x$ for $x \neq 0$. You should be able to show with the open sets definition that this function is discontinuous.